# JSON parse error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: json, swift, xcode7, asmx

I am new to Xcode and Swift and have the below code that shows error on `print(parseJSON)`.

> Error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct
>   format.

The code is posting data correctly to the server, but the response cannot be parsed.

JSON response from my ASMX page:

```
{"status":"Success","message":"User is registered"}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

```
// Send data to server side

let myURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.examle.com/Info.asmx/Testing")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myURL!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let postString = "Email=\(userEmail!)&Password=\(userPassword!)"
print(postString)

request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
    data, response, error in

    if error != nil {
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    //var err: NSError?
    do{
        if let parseJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary{
            print(parseJSON) // ERROR HERE

            let resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String
            print("result: \(resultValue)")

            var isUserRegistered:Bool = false
            if (resultValue == "Success") {
                isUserRegistered = true
            }

            var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["message"] as! String!

            if (!isUserRegistered){
                messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String!
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){ action in
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                }

                myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
         print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}

task.resume()
```

Comment: So what do you see when you print `data`?

Comment: It throws the error at 'if let parseJSON' and goes to '} catch let error as NSError {'.
The error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: You didn't answer the question.

Comment: It does not throw an error in the app itself. It shows it in the debug panel in Xcode. It shows: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: So, on what line does it fail?

Comment: It fails on:
if let parseJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary{

Comment: Sorry about the miscommunication.

Comment: Right, and it's complaining about `data`.  So what value is contained in `data`???

Comment: {"status":"Success","message":"User is registered"}

Comment: And that's in an NSData object?

Comment: That is what the ASMX web service page returns - am able to emulate outside of Xcode

Comment: And that's in an NSData object?

Comment: Cannot say for sure - that's beyond my pay grade :(

Comment: Time to learn how to debug.

Comment: @Hot Licks I'm getting the same issue. Its an NSData object. Is it bcz of  an invalid JSON format?

Comment: @Balasubramanian -- Time to learn how to debug.  Dump the data and read it!!!